# How to release multiple helium balloons simultaneously?

Tags: home-automation

Not sure if this question is on-topic for this site.
I am planning a surprise and I want to have multiple helium balloons that are attached somewhere outside.
The challenge is that I want to release some or all of them into the air simultaneaously.
I can tie some together and release them at once by cutting one string. But how can I cut multiple strings at once?
I also thought about using some remote controlled devices for that, maybe some robots that can grip/release.
Can someone help me out?

Comment: Spare the people downwind the plastic trash. Rent some doves (white homing pigeons) to release instead.

Comment: Also those balloons are dangerous to animals that might eat them by accident.  Can have them in long box/es tied with a string.  open the box and the balloons fly up just so far.  After you pull them back down.

Comment: Also helium is an important non-renewal resource and it shouldn't be wasted on balloons.

Comment: @crip659 good idea! But how could I open all the boxes automatically?

Comment: Simple would be hook and eyes to keep the lids closed.  Depending on the amount of balloons/boxes, strings on the hooks should be able to be pulled all at once, the balloons should then open the lids up.  You want the boxes anchor down, but with light weight lids

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is most certainly not about home improvement.

Comment: Yes, but there doesn‘t seem to be another site where it fits better. And in a sense, this surprise *will* improve my home.

Comment: "there doesn‘t seem to be another site where it fits better" doesn't make it on-topic here. There isn't necessarily a Stack Exchange site for every possible question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tie a loop in the end of each balloon string. Put a pin through all of the loops, trapping them between a pair of outer plates. Tie a string to the pin so that you can pull it from a distance. Repeat the pattern for each balloon station.